# Continuity of a function that glues two functions

Tags: general-topology

$X$ a top, Space. $A$,$B$ closed subsets of $X$ and $X = A \cup B$. Let $f : A \to Y$ and $g: B \to Y$ be continuous functions such that for each $x \in A \cap B$, $f(x) = g(x)$., then the function $f \cup g : X \to Y $

$$f\cup g(x) =\begin{cases}
f, & \text{if }x \in A \\
g, & \text{if }x \in B
\end{cases} $$

is continuous.

### attempt

Take closed set $F \subseteq Y$. We need to show that $(f \cup g)^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $X$. By hypothesis, $f^{-1}(F) $ and $g^{-1}(F)$ must be closed. Since $X = A \cup B$, then we know $(f \cup g)^{-1}(F)$ must lie either in $A$, $B$ or $A \cap B$. In either case, we see $(f \cup g)^{-1}(F)$ is closed. Hence the result.

Do we really need the conditions that $A$, $B$ closed? or not? what if we dropped it? do we still have the result?

Is this correct? I would love to hear some feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Note that a subset of a closed set might not be closed. e.g. $(0,1)\subset [0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not true that $(f\cup g)^{-1}[F]$ must lie in $A$, $B$, or $A\cap B$: it might even be all of $A\cup B=X$. What is true is that

$$(f\cup g)^{-1}[F]=f^{-1}[F]\cup g^{-1}[F]\;,$$

where $f^{-1}[F]$ is closed in $A$, and $g^{-1}[F]$ is closed in $B$. Since $A$ and $B$ are closed in $X$, it follows that $f^{-1}[F]$ and $g^{-1}[F]$ are closed in $X$, and therefore so is their union. Thus, $f\cup g$ is continuous.

Note that I used the hypothesis that $A$ and $B$ are closed in $X$. Counterexamples are possible without that hypothesis. For example, let $X=[0,2]$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R$, let $A=[0,1)$, let $B=[1,2]$, let $f(x)=0$ for $x\in A$, and let $g(x)=1$ for $x\in B$. Then $f$ is continuous on $A$, $g$ is continuous on $B$, and it’s vacuously true that $f(x)=g(x)$ for each $x\in A\cap B$, since $A\cap B=\varnothing$, but $f\cup g$ is clearly not continuous on $X$.

Comment: thank you Brian. But, I have question (maybe silly) though: Why is it true $(f\cup g)^{-1}[F]=f^{-1}[F]\cup g^{-1}[F]\;,$ ? Can you explain this to me? thanks

Comment: @DonAnselmo: $x\in(f\cup g)^{-1}[F]$ iff $(f\cup g)(x)\in F$ iff either $x\in A\setminus B$ and $f(x)\in F$, or $x\in B\setminus A$ and $g(x)\in F$, or $x\in A\cap B$ and $f(x)=g(x)\in F$. This is the case iff $x\in f^{-1}[F]$ or $x\in g^{-1}[F]$.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma , that covers the cases of both open and closed.